# how to insert query and save json data into sql server using nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, json, express

I am trying to insert query into SQL Server using window authentication with nodejs. I have done with get request of select query. but now am trying the post request with insert query. But I can't pass my req.body.address into the following query. the address data have json value.

here my code
[image]

here my request data,

[image: Request data]

the sql table row,
[image: Sql tabel address row]

That is the error,
[image]

Comment: You should post in textual form instead of image. What MySQL version is this? It's much helpful if you can run `SHOW CREATE TABLE users;` and post the result [into your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61317363/edit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `mysql` library is probably, by default, applying a standard string conversion to `req.body.address`. When you do this to a javascript object you obtain `[object Object]`:

```js
req.body.address.toString() // "[object Object]"
```

Objects needs to be converted to string using `JSON.stringify()`:

```js
"user_address": JSON.stringify(req.body.address)
```

Comment: Good to hear! You can choose it as the correct answer with the tick icon

Answer (score 1):

You need to save as string in user_address field.

eg:
If you want to save as address like this:

```
user_address: `${req.body.address.street},${req.body.address.district},${req.body.address.city}`
```

Or

```
user_address: JSON.stringify(req.body.address)
```

whenever you want to show the address you need to do **JSON.parse(user_address)**.

In nutshell, value must be a single value.